# JQuery UI Datepicker Used To Select DOB Not Showing All Months

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using JQuery UI Datepicker for users to select their date of birth (DOB). My codes are as follows :-

```
$('#DOB').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: new Date(),
    yearRange: '-100:+0'
});
```

However, I noticed today that since its January, its not showing the rest of the months, (Feb to Dec) unless I changed the year to previous year. I did a temporary solution by adding another option

```
showMonthAfterYear: true
```

Its not a perfect fix as its only "pushing" users to select the year before selecting the months. Another solution was to change the options as shown below

```
yearRange: '-100:-1'
```

The above 2 temporary solutions might help others but I am hoping for a permanent solution if there is one. Thanks again.

Comment: Duplicate question (without answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120408/jquery-ui-datepicker-display-all-12-months-in-select-for-current-year

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue may be maxDate: new Date(). That sets the maxdate to be today and will hence not show the rest of the months

Comment: yeah, The maxDate will set your maximum date to the current dateTime of the system. You should leave this out of your options than it will be set to null by default and this will enable all the years to come on your datepicker. More info here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Comment: I do agree, in a way, about your comments on me using maxDate that caused this issue but the simple logic behind this is that I want to disable future dates as nobody will have their date of birth tomorrow. :P